# Repository returns different packages on two different machines

Tags: repository, kodi

So I'm trying to get Kodi 15.2 Isengard installed onto my media computer (old pentium, 512MB RAM). Went through some procedures gleaned from the internet which included adding the kodi-old  repository. apt-cache policy returns this:

```
Kodi:
Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2:17.0~git20170210.1529-final-0xenial
  Version table:
     2:17.0~git20170210.1529-final-0xenial 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-kodi/stable/ubuntu       xenial/main i386 Packages
 2:16.1~git20160425.1001-final-0xenial 500
    500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/kodi-old/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
 15.2+dfsg1-3ubuntu1.1 500
    500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages
    500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe i386 Packages
 15.2+dfsg1-3ubuntu1 500
    500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
```

After a couple of mis-starts, I got Isengard installed.

I did this on my main computer (Pentium 4, 2G RAM running Ubuntu 16.04.3, Gnome environment)  to make sure it worked.

I immediately went to my media computer (Ubuntu 14.04.5, Lubuntu environment), added the exact same repository, but apt-cache policy kodi returns this:

```
kodi:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2:17.4+git20170822.1009-final-0trusty
  Version table:
     2:17.4+git20170822.1009-final-0trusty 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
     2:16.1~git20160424.1410-final-0trusty 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/kodi-old/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386
```

How is it possible for the same repository, checked with almost identical machines, to return different available packages?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

they are NOT the same repos. one I note is XENIAL 16.04, the other TRUSTY 14.04.

Even if the URL is the same, the version keyword (xenial/trusty) points to a different place at the end of the url.   The repo. name consists of URL & the rest of the info you see in your `sources.list` record.

Comment: sources.list contains nothing relating to kodi ... old or new. /sources.list.d on the computer I was able to install kodi on has files that are kodi-old-xenial.list and ~.list.save. On the computer i want kodi installed to, /sources.list.d has kodi-old-trusty.list and ~list.save. I copied the xenial.list and xenial.list.save files from the one computer to the other, apt-get update, apt-cache policy kodi, but still no joy. I'm confused as to why adding the exact same ppa to two computers yields different results.

Comment: @akwusmc - what you're attempting to do is being stopped by Ubuntu's (debian dpkg et.al) packaging defense in order to preserve the functioning, stability & reliability of the OS.  I applaud your 'testing' on another system before putting into production (media.comp), but for it to be valid they should be the same OS (inc. version) though if a program rarely changes (eg. mousepad editor) it may be okay.  When you copied a sources.list file from one machine to another I assume you altered (sed et.al.)  xenial->trusty; if you didn't it'd be very risky without a long lib evaluation/test..

Comment: didn't fix my problem but it DID help! I was able to find a copy of the Kodibuntu iso so I've gone a different route. But in the meantime, I've been able to learn a bit about ssh, scp, and sftp so it's not been a total loss! Thanks again!